# Firebase Firestore dummy variable in document path name and usage

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

What is the formal name for using { } in a firestore document path. For example:

```js
firestore.document('/links/{id}')
```

I read documentation and know it is a dummy/replacement variable for any document with that path but can't remember the name of it and can't figure out the right search terms for it.

I want to search up in the documentation whether {id} then can be used as a variable with the actual document name assigned to it. Or if there is another way to get the actual document name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only time something like `{id}` is supported in Firestore using wildcards with security rules or Cloud Functions triggers.  It's ahrd to tell exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but in either case, it's called a wildcard.

The syntax you're showing can't be used as a form of variable substitution.  If you need put a variable in a document path in JavaScript, you should use JavaScript's own syntax for variable substitution.  You might be thinking of backtick strings with variable interpolation that goes like this:

```
firestore.document(`/links/${id}`)
```

This syntax has nothing to do with Firestore.  It is just JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm using it in a cloud function listener. My goal is to listen for a document delete in collection 'links' and then create a new document with the same name at a different location. I was hoping that the wildcard {id} would somehow store the name of the deleted document to make it easy to create the new one. Otherwise I will just make a field that stores the document name so I can retrieve it from the delete snapshot.

Comment: The wildcard does become a variable.  I suggest reading the documentation about it. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#wildcards-parameters